# Strict concavity and tangent line

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Let $f: A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function on the open and convex set $A$. We know that $f$ is concave on $A$ if and only if $f(\textbf{x}) \leq f(\textbf{x}^0) + (\textbf{x} - \textbf{x}^0)^T \, \nabla f(\textbf{x}^0), \; \forall \textbf{x}, \textbf{x}^0 \in A$. Is it true that $f$ is strictly concave on $A$ if and only if the following holds? $f(\textbf{x}) < f(\textbf{x}^0) + (\textbf{x} - \textbf{x}^0)^T \, \nabla f(\textbf{x}^0), \; \forall \textbf{x} \neq \textbf{x}^0 \in A$.